# Where's 'Draw Eraser'?

Tags: microsoft-word

[image: d?]

[Here's](https://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/align-text-inside-tables-microsoft-word/) where I downloaded the picture on the left.  I input 'Draw Eraser' in 'Tell me what you want to do', but nothing resulted.

Scott Basham also mentions the 'Eraser' in [*Word 2019 in easy steps*](http://ineasysteps.com/products-page/all_books/word-2019-easy-steps/). p. 91.

Comment: The ribbon is customizable. It may simply not be in the default configuration. /edit: Well scratch that, it *is* in the default configuration.

Comment: Is your own system running Word 2016?

Comment: @grawity Yes. This feature appears in Google search results for Word 2016, but I'll be updating to Word 2019 soon.

Comment: It looks like a number of icons aren't showing on your toolbar.  The toolbars are customizable.  You can add and delete specific icons (including accidentally).  You may need to hunt for them, or re-add the missing icons.  It might be worth just reinstalling Word to get back to the default configuration.  Whatever's going on with your Word, it isn't behaving in the default way.  Nobody on the site will know how your installation got that way.  In case you discover still more missing icons, it's really the same story.  A separate question about each missing icon won't be helpful for you.

Comment: For a quick workaround, add Eraser to the Quick Access Tool bar and it will always be available.